# Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80

Tags: dual-boot, apt, updates, lubuntu

I've read about a dozen `sudo apt-get update` questions and tried the solutions that were suggested there. None of them worked. I just installed Lubuntu 15.04 on my laptop, dual booting it alongside Windows 8. When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get these errors:

```
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease                                                                                                                       
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease       
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease     
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg             
  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Fetched 19.7 kB in 2min 0s (163 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is    unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
```

Here's my sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)]/  vivid main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you change your mirror service, as **`ph.archive.ubuntu.com`** doesn't seem to resolve, either because the subdomain has been dropped or there's some kind of weird proxy problem.

Solution: Replace all instances of **`ph.archive.ubuntu.com`** with **`archive.ubuntu.com`** i.e. remove **`ph.`** from the urls, leaving everything else as it is.